# pyMPI build & install

Tags: python, mpi, cluster-computing

Hi everyone I'm trying to install pyMPI on ubuntu server 10.04.2 .
When i run ./configure this is what it prints out

```
enter 
root@ACRS-CN1:/usr/local/src/pyMPI-2.5b0# ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking host overrides... no
checking fatal error on cancel of isend (--with-bad-cancel)... no
checking Assume stdin is interactive (--with-isatty)...
checking Append a newline to prompt (--with-prompt-nl)...
checking for mpcc... no
checking for mpxlc... no
checking for mpiicc... no
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether mpicc accepts -g... yes
checking for mpicc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of mpicc... none
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for mpicc is really C++... checking how to run the C preprocessor... mpicc    checking for egrep... grep -E
no
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for grep... /bin/grep
checking for mpiCC... no
checking for mpi++... no
checking for mpicC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking for mpicc... /usr/bin/mpicc
checking for g++... /usr/bin/g++
checking if /usr/bin/mpicc -E -w is a valid CPP... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/mpicc -E -w
checking for --with-python... no
checking executable /usr/bin/python2.6... yes
checking for Python... /usr/bin/python2.6
checking for MPIRun.exe... no
checking for mpirun... /usr/bin/mpirun
checking for mvrun... no
checking for poe... no
checking for nopoe... no
checking Python version 2.2 or higher... yes
checking distutils?... yes
checking distutils works... yes
checking Numeric?...
checking Numpy?...
checking Python version string... 2.6checking install prefix for /usr/bin/python2.6... /usr
checking Prefix exists...... yes
checking for python include location... /usr/include/python2.6
checking that include directory exists... yes
checking for python library location... /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
checking that lib directory is accessable... yes
checking for python lib/config location... /usr/lib/python2.6/config
checking that lib/config directory is accessable... yes
checking libpython2.6.a is there... not there
 configure: WARNING: If you get link errors add a --with-libs=-L/path/to/dir where   libpython2.6.a lives
 checking configuration Makefile is there... yes
 checking module configuration table is there... not there
 configure: error: config.c wasn't where I thought it was
 root@ACRS-CN1:/usr/local/src/pyMPI-2.5b0#
```

code here

configure: error: config.c wasn't where I thought it was

what does this mean and how can i fix it?

Comment: sounds like you need python development files

Comment: @Anycorn Thanks that did the trick apt-get install python-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libopenmpi-dev
```

are needed to build successfully. Just tested right now.